# Jenkins CloudFoundry plugin timeout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloud-foundry

We are using Jenkins CF plugin to deploy. Frequently, we run into issues where the Plugin simply timesout with the below:

> 00:46:06 Cloud Foundry Plugin:
>   00:48:07 java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>   00:48:07   at >reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:259)
>   00:48:07   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:243)
>   00:48:07   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:360)
>   00:48:07   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:72)
>   00:48:07   at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:113)
>   00:48:07   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   00:48:07   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

Refering to the plugin documentation (https://github.com/jenkinsci/cloudfoundry-plugin), the timeout and pluginTimeout have been gradually bumped up to be 600 secs. Yet the process consistently fails in approximately 120 secs (~2 mins).

Is the provided timeout value not picked up or does it simply override it with the default?

Any inputs would greatly help!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to wrap the code in timeout:

```
      timeout(time: 200, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                            pushToCloudFoundry(...) 
  }
```

Applying the timeout at the stage or node level did not do the trick. It had to be done at the operation-level.